# Having Trouble Extending Dotfill in the Usual Way with Book Class

Tags: table-of-contents, geometry, tocloft, book-class, dotfill

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[showframe,margin=.3in,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]{geometry}
\textheight=5.25in
\usepackage[frame,noinfo,center]{crop}

\usepackage{tocloft}

% To extend the dots in the Table of Contents over to the Page no.
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\dotfill}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont \bfseries} % Changes chapter font in TOC.
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries\small} % Changes font\fontsize for chapter page number in TOC.

\begin{document}
\normalsize
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\centering\textbf{Chapter Title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER I}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{}
\end{document}
```

which produces the TOC

[image]

In the past, to extend the Chapter dotfill in the TOC, something like this worked:

`\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\dotfill}` ;

however, my document now is a small book in which I am invoking the geometry package. I don't know for sure if this may be causing the problem.

QUESTION: For the code given above, how may I extend the dots all the way over to the page number in the TOC?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book class, the space assigned to the page number for the chapters is 1.5em and the numbers are right aligned in that box.

It can be changed to another value, for example using
`\cftsetpnumwidth{1.5ex}` for a single digit page number.

[image: a]

The chosen width must be tested with two-digit page numbers.
[image: c]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
    \usepackage[showframe,margin=.3in,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=6in]{geometry}
\textheight=5.25in
\usepackage[frame,noinfo,center]{crop}

\usepackage{tocloft}

% To extend the dots in the Table of Contents over to the Page no.
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\bfseries\dotfill}    
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont \bfseries} % Changes chapter font in TOC.
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\bfseries\small} % Changes font\fontsize for chapter page number in TOC.

\cftsetpnumwidth{1.5ex}%width for  single page numbers, added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \normalsize
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    
    \centering\textbf{Chapter Title}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER I}
    \newpage
%   \setcounter{page}{30} % Try two digits page numbers <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%   \centering\textbf{Chapter Title II}
%   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER II}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this very helpful and informative answer.